# Conversion from type 'Guid' to type 'String' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have this code , which is supposed to check if value is nothing

```
_Attendee.TransactionID = If((a.tGatewayTrxID Is Nothing), Guid.NewGuid(), a.tGatewayTrxID.ToString)
```

The last part of this code is throwing exception "Conversion from type 'Guid' to type 'String' is not valid."  I know that `IIF` evaluates each part of the statement, `If` is not supposed to do that.  I use this same code all over the place and it always catches null or Nothing values - why is it not working in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If TransactionID is a string I believe you just need to change Guid.NewGuid() to Guid.NewGuid().ToString().

Comment: oh man , yea - its getting late - that means it's time to go to sleep there, I'll accept tomorrow when it lets me - thanks @PeterJ